# How to get app permision from Pinterest for authenticating account, fetching pins, fetching boards and posting on board

Tags: node.js, pinterest

We have created a Pinterest app for performing the following operations on our website:

1. Authenticating Pinterest account
2. Getting Boards and their pins
3. Creating boards
4. Posting pins onto Pinterest boards via our website

We have had applied for our app approval. But it is not yet been approved.

May I know why it is getting rejected and also do you guys have any suggestions for us to improve our approval procedure?